# How to send and receive using AJAX and JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to setup a simple AJAX call that sends it's data via JSON to my PHP script, which then returns the data.

But I am having no luck.

Here is my code for sending:

```
$.ajax({
      url: ROOT+'Address/fetchAddress',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        json: {
          "Id":"0",
          "Name":"Jim"
        }
      },
      error: function(a, b)
      {
        alert(b)
      },
      success: function(data)
      {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(data)
      }
    })
```

Serverside:

```
public function fetchAddress()
  {
    $JSON = $_POST['json'];
    echo json_decode($JSON);
  }
```

But I am getting "parseerror" in alert box and if I inspect the response I get:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...public_html\controllers\Address.php on line 20
```

Comment: You have two issues, both to do with data types. Your server-side code is expecting the `json` POST parameter to be a string, and it's not. Your jQuery AJAX call is expecting the server's response to be valid JSON, and it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a conceptual mistake here.

When you say `dataType: 'json'` it means returned data is in JSON format.

You are still sending data in a POST array

```
public function fetchAddress(){
    echo $_POST['json'];
}
```

to fetch the data

To pick up on the other side you have a pre-passed object (as data is returned as JSON)

So

```
success: function(data)
  {

    alert(data.id+"NAME"+data.name);
  }
```

(Oh and your data is not a string (which a post expects) and JSON is so clean it up into a nice string

```
json: '{"Id":"0","Name":"Jim"}'
```

Comment: Thanks, setting it up as a string sorted it. I understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

The data your PHP receives does not need to be decoded, as it is already an array. Just change your function to this and you should be fine

```
public function fetchAddress()
{
  echo json_encode($_POST['json']);
}
```

Also, since you have said jQuery that your response is a json, there is no need to call $.parseJSON() to your fetched data

Comment: Haste is a bad consultant... Fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call sends the data as an array and expects the returned data as JSON, so the PHP function should look like

```
public function fetchAddress()
{
    $data = $_POST['json'];
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and the client side need not decode the returned data, because it specified `dataType: 'json'` and then this is already done by the `ajax` function

```
$.ajax({
      url: ROOT+'Address/fetchAddress',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      ...
      success: function(data)
      {
        alert(data)
      }
    });
```